# Why am I seeing a comment in red color, blocking access to the flag button?

Tags: support, comments, design, mathjax

Nat comment on [Operation Unz̖̬̜̺̬a͇͖̯͔͉l̟̭g͕̝̼͇͓̪͍o̬̝͍̹̻](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/188472/operation-unz%cc%96%cc%ac%cc%9c%cc%ba%cc%aca%cd%87%cd%96%cc%af%cd%94%cd%89l%cc%9f%cc%adg%cd%95%cc%9d%cc%bc%cd%87%cd%93%cc%aa%cd%8do%cc%ac%cc%9d%cd%8d%cc%b9%cc%bb), when copy-pasted, looks like:

> @L.F.                    Too late... ...far too late...                   Too late... ...far too late...                   Too late... ...far too late...                   Too late... ...far too late...                   Too late... ...far too late...                   Too late... ...far too late...                   Too late... ...far too late...

But visually, it has a red color rendering on Chrome 75 on macOS:
[image]

What is the reason for this? Unicode can change the color of the text? Or is there a CSS/JS issue?

Note that I can't even easily reach the flag button for this comment, as it's cove**red** by the text itself: 
[image]

Answer (score 9):

It's actually a MathJax formula, not a Unicode issue. The source of the MathJax formula gives us:

> \def\x#1{\smash{\rlap{\hskip{-10em}\style{transform-origin: center middle; display: inline-block; transform: rotate(#1deg); padding: 3em}{\huge{\color{red}{~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\text{Too late...}~\text{...far too late...}}}}}}} \def\y#1{\x{#1}\x{-#1}} {\y{10}\y{25}\y{40}\y{70}}

To see this raw form and to get access to the surrounding buttons (like the flag button), you can change the renderer of MathJax with a right click and choose "Plain Source":
[image]

And it will show in plain text, giving you access to all the surrounding buttons:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Clicks on the delete button worked just fine... Next time, flag the post for moderators to delete the comment.

Comment: Why do we need MathJax in comments?

Comment: @ShaWiz If the users of MathJax-enabled sites don't find it useful, you'd see active requests to have it removed...

Comment: @Sonic maybe now that it's being abused?